# Error with memoir and titletoc package when adding chapter to ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, memoir, titletoc

I'm using the memoir documentclass, and I'm tring to customize the table of contents style. For this, I'm using the package `titletoc`, and the command `\titlecontents` for the formatting. What works ok for `section` and `subsection` fails for `chapter`, with the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.

<argument> \@chapapp@head 

\@cftbsnum 1\@cftasnum 

l.3 ...er}{\chapternumberline {1}first chapter}{3}%

?
```

Here is a MWE that reproduces the error for me. It's happening with both pdflatex and lualatex (at least, I didn't try others). If `\documentclass{memoir}` is replaced with `\documentclass{book}`, everything works fine.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vskip0pt}{\small\thecontentslabel.\ }{}{\small\dotfill\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}[0pt]{\vskip0pt}{\qquad\small\thecontentslabel.\ }{}{\small\dotfill\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[0pt]{\vskip0pt}{\qquad \qquad \small\thecontentslabel.\ }{}{\small\dotfill\contentspage}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

test
\chapter{first chapter}
Contents of first chapter.
\section{first section}
Contents of first section.
\chapter{second chapter}
contents of second chapter.
\section{second section}
Contents of second section.
\subsection{First subsection}
Contents of first subsection
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know `titletoc` is not compatible with `memoir` in the first place. What exactly are you trying to do? Then perhaps we can create a purely `memoir` based solution

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I'm trying to replicate a complex word document I have with LaTeX, and it's almost done, but this is one of the last things I cannot solve. I would like to have the table of contents with all elements (chapter, section and subsection) in uppercase and a smaller font size. Chapters are not working, but sections and subsections are. For example, this works for section and subsection, but not for chapter: \titlecontents{section}[0pt]{\vskip0pt}{\qquad\small\thecontentslabel.\ }{}{\small\dotfill\contentspage}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see this seem to do the trick. I'm not quite sure if the box redefinition is wanted, but you can just leave it out

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\normalfont\small}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont\small}
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{.\ }
\setlength\cftbeforechapterskip{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsectionfont{\normalfont\small}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionfont{\normalfont\small}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsectionfont{\normalfont\small}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionaftersnum}{.\ }
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionaftersnum}{.\ }
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionaftersnum}{.\ }
\renewcommand\numberlinebox[2]{#2}
\renewcommand\chapternumberlinebox[2]{#2}

\settocdepth{subsubsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\listoffigures*

test
\chapter{first chapter}
Contents of first chapter.
\section{first section}
Contents of first section.
\chapter{second chapter}
contents of second chapter.
\section{second section}
Contents of second section.
\subsection{First subsection}
Contents of first subsection
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! Seems to be working, I will continue from here!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your comment that you wanted the elements in uppercase, which daleif's answer did not do although it did the other things you wanted. To make chapter entries uppercase do:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\small\MakeUppercase}
```

and similarly add `\MakeUppercase` to the `\cftsectionfont`, `\cftsubsectionfont`, etc.

Comment: Better use `\MakeTextUppercase `, but under the latest memoir it is the same thing (we load textcase with the overload option)

Comment: @daleif I bow to your superior memory :-)

Comment: I just changed it in the latest memoir release. We no longer embed a copy of textcase, we load the real thing. When the ltx team is already on it why no use their work.